# Angular2 Firebase Background Images

Tags: angular, firebase, background-image, angularfire2

I'm using Angular2 and Firebase to bring in data.

Right now this works for regular images:

```
<img src="{{brew.image}}">
```

For some reason, I can't get the image to show as a background image.

I've tried this, but nothing seems to work.

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + brew.image + ')'}"></div>
```

Any thoughts???

Comment: is there any errors in console log ? please post them.

Comment: No errors. I'm kind of stumped on this one.

Comment: 'url(" ' + brew.image + ' ")'   use this and check again